# Spark 2.4x - how do we set default.parallelism & sql.shuffle to optimize performance during an autoscaling event?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

To optimize performance, we don't want too many data partitions or too few data partitions, so during an autoscaling event, we'd like to adjust `default.parallelism` and `sql.shuffle` dynamically. Where can this be set that takes effect on the Spark cluster (running on aws-emr)?

I've tried to set this dynamically on the driver node, but when I look at the environment tab, the `defaul.parallelism` and `sql.shuffle` values doesn't change. I suspect I have to do this on the master node, since Spark UI runs on master node.[image]

I'm thinking I'd have to set these values in the master node, but how can this be done within a Spark application or does this have to be done elsewhere?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question ? I am afraid this is not possible. How to choose a suitable value if the size of your cluster will change...

Comment: @PaulPraet it looks like environment variables don't change, but internally, the values change. We're going to spark 3 so it has internals that handles this issue dynamically I believe.